# Split a table into two related tables based on distinct and non distinct columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with distinct columns and with non distinct columns which I would like to break to related tables.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume the following table:

```
original
    id | product | vendor  |  attr
    ----------------------------------
    1    phone     ebay      some attr a
    2    t.v       amazon    some attr b
    3    phone     paypal    some attr c
    4    t.v       google    some attr d
```

And assume I'd like creating two related tables like so:

```
table_a
id | product 
--------------
1    phone 
2    t.v    

table_b
id | table_a_ref | vendor | attr
----------------------------------
1      1           ebay     attr a
2      1           paypal   attr c
3      2           amazon   attr b
4      2           google   attr d
```

I can't match the correct new id's in table_a to their reference field in table b.

For example with distinct:

```
WITH products AS (
    INSERT INTO table_a (product)
    SELECT DISTINCT product
    FROM original 
    RETURNING id
  )
INSERT INTO table_b (table_a_ref, vendor, attr)
-- How do I refer to the right reference id and correlate it to table_A?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your CTE is already returning the information you need, I believe you can do that without referring to `table_a` at all. But in case you need this info in the table anyway, you might wanna try this:

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE original (id INT, product TEXT, vendor TEXT, attr TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table_a (id SERIAL, product TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table_b (id INT, table_a_ref INT, vendor TEXT, attr TEXT);

INSERT INTO original VALUES
(1,'phone','ebay','some attr a'),
(2,'t.v','amazon','some attr b'),
(3,'phone','paypal','some attr c'),
(4,'t.v','google','some attr d');
```

Query to populate `table_a` and `table_b` at once:

```
WITH j AS (
  INSERT INTO table_a (product) 
  SELECT DISTINCT(product) FROM original
  ORDER BY product
  RETURNING id,product)
INSERT INTO table_b
SELECT original.id, j.id, original.vendor, original.attr 
FROM original
JOIN j ON j.product = original.product
ORDER BY original.id;
```

And here is the content of `table_a` ..

```
SELECT * FROM table_a;

 id | product 
----+---------
  1 | phone
  2 | t.v
(2 rows)
```

.. and `table_b`

```
SELECT * FROM table_b;

 id | table_a_ref | vendor |    attr     
----+-------------+--------+-------------
  1 |           1 | ebay   | some attr a
  2 |           2 | amazon | some attr b
  3 |           1 | paypal | some attr c
  4 |           2 | google | some attr d
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Of course silly me! quick note is there a reason to "carry" the ids for table_b and assigning them manually?

Comment: Well, it all depends on your use case. If the ids in table `original` are supposed to be sequential, a serial column should suffice and there is no need to insert them manually. And yes, carrying them to `table_b` is imho necessary to identify single transactions. I hope I got your question right